# What to do when curdling occurs?

Tags: sauce, thickening

Are there any methods available to "fix" a sauce that has curdled?

Or, if I can't fix the curdling, is there any way to still use the sauce?  What can I do with it?

Comment: This isn't really a question. Hobodave's answer is the only useful one that will ever happen, anyway.

Comment: I made it into a question.  But unfortunately it's true that there aren't really any good answers.

Comment: What type of sauce is this? Depending on the type of sauce, there are varying methods you would take to uncurdle it

Comment: I am closing this old question, because, as the answers make it obvious, the chosen strategy will be different from every type of sauce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're making a sauce that isn't supposed to curdle, and it does, you throw it out and start over.

Comment: That's not always an option really

Comment: That doesn't make it any less true of an answer.

Comment: A better question to ask would be how to _prevent_ curdling. To that I could contribute much more.

Comment: Yep, Dave's right. Don't even think about trying to blend it or strain it, you'll never get the correct texture back.

Comment: dassouki, sorry, but that is always the only option. If it's curdled, it's garbage. It's technically edible inasmuch as it is unspoiled foodstuff, but beyond that? it's garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Add 1/4 cup boiling water to the curdled sauce, wisk gently, and repeat until sauce is smoothed out. Re-season and serve promptly. This isn't a 100% cure but if throwing out the sauce isn't an option then boiling hot water is the closest thing to a fix you can get.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem...

The sauce with milk turned into Curds and oil.

I was cooking it in a crockpot with chicken.

I added a bunch of Quinoa, and let that cook.   The quinoa soaked up the oil, it made everything look much better, it tasted great.